# DevDemon Subscriptions - Your card was declined

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions, devdemon-subscriptions

I'm using DevDemon Subscriptions 1.5.3 and EE 2.9.2.  I've installed the demo templates, set up some subscriptions and added the Stripe details.  When I try and make a payment using the Stripe test cards, it comes back saying Your card was declined.

Is there anything else I need to do to put through some test payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you setup your Test public key on the page and use approved Test Cards from Stripe.

https://stripe.com/docs/testing

This should work appropriately.